# Filling a simple SVG in a div

Tags: html, css, svg

Here is my relevant HML with SVG:

```html
     <div style="width:24px;height:24px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background:black;">
        <svg   viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="red" d="M24 12l-9-9v7h-15v4h15v7z"/>
        </svg>
     </div>
```

It renders fine but leaves padding above and below the arrow inside the div.

I tried using SVG as background to the div after base64 encoding the SVG tag, as in:

```html
    <div style="width:24px; height:24px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSJyZWQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0ic2NhbGUoMSwxKSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNMjQgMTJsLTktOXY3aC0xNXY0aDE1djd6Ii8+PC9zdmc+');">
     </div>
```

It displays nothing!

Yes there are similar questions asked but this is NOT a duplicate. Nothing in the answers posted to similar questions on SO resolve this problem.

Comment: you need to adjust the viewbox: https://jsfiddle.net/103vyL78/

Comment: @Temani Afif Yes... adding height:18px to the div and viewbox set to "0 3 24 18" did it.  If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @enxaneta you can propbably add a more accurate answer than mine showing how to find the viewbox using a function (like you did in a previous answers). It would be better than my trial and error method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure I understand your question. Maybe this is what you need:

I've changed the viewBox to `viewBox="0 3 24 18"`. In order to get this value I've console.log(thePath.getBBox())

The method `getBBox()` returns an object with the position and the size of the bounding box of the path. I'm using this values for the new `viewBox`

`viewBox = bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height`

Where bb is the bounding box.

```html
<div style="width:24px;height:18px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background:black;">
        <svg viewBox="0 3 24 18">
          <path id="thePath" fill="red" d="M24 12l-9-9v7h-15v4h15v7z"/>
        </svg>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is the correct and fully working solution.

Answer (score 1):

The fill needs to be on the `path` instead of the `svg` element.

Also, try adding the `width="24"` and `height="24"` to the `svg` element.

Comment: You are right but that was my mistake in typing the issue. I fixed it but that does not solve the main problem of space above and below the arrow inside the div. Adding width and height to the svg element also does not help. I tried it earlier.