# How can I make the SVG circle fill the whole box?

Tags: html, svg

I've this circle here in SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="532" height="532" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <circle cx="255" cy="255" r="230" fill="{c}" />
    <text x="255" y="246" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" font-size="275" font-weight="300" font-family="Roboto">{x}</text>
</svg>
```

I need this for a font generator and I want to remove the space between the outside and the circle so that I get a PNG without any space. How can I do this?

Comment: Use this `viewBox="25 25 460 460"` instead of `viewBox="0 0 512 512"` In order to get the values for the `viewBox`you need the circle's bounding box. To get the circle's bounding box you can do `circle.getBBox()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Please write a short answer that I can mark it as helpful and you get a bit of a reward :)

Comment: Thank you M.Jo. I appreciate it a lot.  As a mater of fact I've answered this question so many times that I'm ashamed to answer it again. Yesterday - for example -  I've answered a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450020/filling-a-simple-svg-in-a-div/56450939#56450939

Comment: OH, I'm sorry. I'll give you a thumbs up!

Comment: @enxaneta I've marked my question as duplicate. Now it's better ;)